# ¿A qué archivos exactamente tiene permiso la app con un ID de usuario asignado por el sistema?

Tags: android

> De forma predeterminada, el sistema le asigna a cada aplicación un ID
> de usuario de Linux único (solo el sistema utiliza el ID y la
> aplicación lo desconoce). El sistema establece permisos para todos los
> archivos en una aplicación de modo que solo el ID de usuario asignado
> a esa aplicación pueda acceder a ellos.

Cada aplicación tiene un ID para saber que privilegios tiene, mí duda está aquí exactamente:

> El sistema establece permisos para todos los
> archivos

No sé a qué archivos se refiere, quería ver si ustedes podrían decirme.

¿Son los archivos de recursos de la app o a archivos almacenados en el dispositivo?

Fuentes de las citas:
[Aspectos fundamentales de la app](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bases de datos o preferencias creadas por la aplicación. Está hecho para que otras aplicaciones no puedan acceder a la información que guardan las otras, así como tampoco a información propia del sistema.

También se aplica a recursos del propio sistema como el gps, el bluetooth... para tener acceso a ellos el usuario debe dar los permisos personalmente.
Es decir, por defecto, una app *solo tiene permisos para acceder a sus propios archivos*.

Comment: Gracias, aceptaré la respuesta.